# How to print list elements one by one by keypress on python

Tags: python, while-loop, pynput

I want to print on the console each word in a sentence, but only when the spacebar is pressed by the user, like this: at the begging nothing happens; then the user press the spacebar and the first word appears and stays there; then he/she presses the spacebar again and the second word appears; and so on:

`<keypress> This <keypress> is <keypress> my <keypress> sentence.`

I've written the code bellow, but I could only make all the words appear simultaneously.

```
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

sentence = 'This is my sentence'

def on_press(key):

    if key == Key.space:

        i = 0
        while True:

            print(sentence.split()[i])
            i = i + 1

            if i == len(sentence.split()):
                break

    elif key == Key.delete:  # Manually stop the process!
        return False

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

SENTENCE = 'This is my sentence'
index = 0
stop = False


def on_press(key):
    global index, stop
    if key == Key.space:
        if index < len(SENTENCE.split()):
            print(SENTENCE.split()[index])
            index += 1
        else:
            stop = True
    elif key == Key.delete:  # Manually stop the process!
        stop = True


with Listener(on_press=on_press, daemon=True) as listener:
    while listener.is_alive() and not stop:
        time.sleep(2)
```